# add a node alphabetically ordered to a doubly linked list in python

Tags: python, list, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

I am doing a project for university. I have a doubly-linked list to define a health center class. Also, I have the patient class:

```
import os.path

class Patient:
    # Class to represent a Patient
    def __init__(self, name, year, covid, vaccine):
        self.name = name
        self.year = year
        self.covid = covid
        self.vaccine = vaccine
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + '\t' + str(self.year) + '\t' + str(self.covid) + '\t' + str(self.vaccine)


class HealthCenter(DList):
    # Class to represent a Health Center
    def __init__(self, filetsv = None):
        super(HealthCenter, self).__init__()

        if filetsv is None or not os.path.isfile(filetsv):
            self.name = ''

        else: 
            print('Loading the data for the health center from the file', filetsv)
    
            self.name = filetsv.replace('.tsv', '')
            tsv_file = open(filetsv)
            read_tsv = csv.reader(tsv_file, delimiter = "\t")
    
    
            for row in read_tsv:
                name = row[0]
                year = int(row[1])
                covid = False
                
                if int(row[2]) == 1:
                    covid = True

                vaccine = int(row[3])
                self.addLast(Patient(name, year, covid, vaccine))
```

> My problem is I have to add the patients in alphabetical order, as nodes, inside the list that the health center is.
> Here is my code:

```
    def addPatient(self, patient):
        new_node = DNode(None)
        new_node.elem = patient
        new_node.elem.name = patient.name
        new_node.elem.year = patient.year
        new_node.elem.covid = patient.covid
        new_node.elem.vaccine = patient.vaccine
        current = self._head
        current.elem = self._head.elem
        
        # if empty
        if self.isEmpty() == True:
            self._head = new_node
            self._tail = new_node
            self.size = 1
        else:
            i = 0
            while current.elem.name != patient.name and current.elem.name < patient.name:
                current = current.next
                i += 1
            if current.elem.name == patient.name:
                if current.elem == patient:
                    return print("This patient already exists")
                else:
                    self.insertAt(i, new_node)
                    return print("WARNING \n A patient with the same name already exists: \n",
                          str(current.elem),"Added patient: \n", patient)
            elif current.elem.name > patient.name:
                return self.insertAt(i-1, new_node)
```

> It gives me the following error

```
  File "C:.../phase 1 spyder.py", line 73, in addPatient
    while (current.elem.name != patient.name) and (current.elem.name < patient.name):

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'elem'
```

> I don't understand why, I have defined in other functions the variable **current** and use it as `current.elem` and `current.elem.name` or another attribute like covid, year or vaccine, and I don´t get this error.

Help pls